# module 'gitlab' has no attribute 'Gitlab'

Tags: python, gitlab

I am trying to read the file from gitlab. I created access token in gitlab for this. Downloaded **module python-gitlab**

I installed **module python-gitlab** from PyCharm: File --> Settings--> Python interpreter --> python-gitlab

```
import gitlab
import json
from pprint import pprint
import requests
import urllib.request
# private token authentication
gl = gitlab.Gitlab('https://gitlab.com/..../CSV_HOMEWORK.csv', private_token='xxx')

gl.auth()

# list all projects
projects = gl.projects.list()
for project in projects:
    # print(project) # prints all the meta data for the project
    print("Project: ", project.name)
    print("Gitlab URL: ", project.http_url_to_repo)
    # print("Branches: ", project.repo_branches)
    pprint(project.repository_tree(all=True))
    f = urllib.request.urlopen(project.http_url_to_repo)
    myfile = f.read()
    print(myfile)
    print("\n\n")
```

after print(gitlab) I have [image]

P.S. My file name from where I run my code isn't gitlab.py

Comment: How did you install the gitlab module? Did you use pip?

Comment: Also, how is your file named? If you named it gitlab.py that may be causing the issue (in that case, just rename your file)

Comment: I installed from PyCharm: File --> Settings--> Python interpreter -->  python-gitlab

Comment: My file name from where I run my code isn't gitlab.py

Comment: What could be wrong? @aaossa

Comment: Question is still opened.

Answer (score 6):

You installed the package `gitlab` instead of `python-gitlab`.

Even if you installed `python-gitlab` already, the `gitlab` package will still conflict, so it must be uninstalled

```
pip uninstall gitlab
pip install python-gitlab
```

Comment: gitlab package is not installed for me.

Comment: @Kaymaz then it sounds like you have a different problem/question

Comment: My problem was the filename was gitlab.py...

Comment: @Kaymaz that was exactly my issue. I hope you're fine with me posting this as an answer so it isn't buried in the comments to an answer and future users find it more easily.

Answer (score 1):

It worked for me after I uninstalled both packages and reinstalled the `python-gitlab` package.

```
pip uninstall gitlab
pip uninstall python-gitlab
pip install python-gitlab
```

Answer (score 0):

Posting [@kaymaz' comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71284958/module-gitlab-has-no-attribute-gitlab#comment130777842_71289694) into an answer so future readers can discover a potential solution more easily:

When your file is named gitlab.py it imports itself instead of the gitlab (or python-gitlab) module. Therefore the above error message appears. Rename the file to something else and it'll work.

Answer (score 0):

The issue can also happen when the file is `gitlab.py`. Renaming the file will solve the issue, when the package is not conflicting with `gitlab`.